# How can I find an specific F-Curve given an action name?

Tags: python, scripting, fcurves

Given action name, a data path and an array index, how can I find the F-Curve associated to that action?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64342/finding-a-specific-fcurve  @David remind me.. do I mark unanswered link  a duplicate of this q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `fcurves.find(data_path, array_index)` function. For example, we want to retrieve the F-Curve for the location’s Z channel, for an action named `ActionName`.

```
# Configuration
action_name = 'ActionName'
data_path = 'location'
array_index = 2

action = bpy.data.actions.get(action_name)
if not action:
    print('Action {} not found.'.format(action_name))
else:
    # Retrieve the specific F-Curve
    fc = action.fcurves.find(data_path, array_index)
    if fc:
        for kfp in fc.keyframe_points:
            print(kfp.handle_left)
            print(kfp.handle_right)
            print(kfp.interpolation)
            print('Frame = {:04}; Value = {}'.format(kfp.co[0], kfp.co[1]))
```

Comment: Use `bpy.data.actions.get(name)` else it will throw a `KeyError`

Comment: @batFINGER, You mean that, if the key is not present, operator[] will throw a `KeyError` exception, while `get()` will return `None`? I updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks.